# How to notify my app about newly available resources on the server to download?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have an app to display images in sequence (as a slideshow). Images are downloaded from the server and stored on the device then it is displayed in a slideshow using ImageView and TimerTask. I would like to tell the app that images have been updated on the server and force it to download them again.

How do I tackle this?

Comment: Do not use push. If the user turns them off you’ve lost core functionality. Look into websickets or polling.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano I was considering fairbase for the job. the app won't be distributed publicly. so I do have control over permissions of the app.

Comment: Firebase is still only a push provider. Both iOS and Android Apps do not afford developers the ability to force push notifications regardless of provider and distribution methods. Anyone can go to settings and disable push on an app-by-app basis. The only way I see this working with push is if you are able to remotely manage the devices using AEM to force settings.

Comment: You are correct @BrandonStillitano. Luckily for my purpose, the application isn't installed on strager's phone or so. The app will be installed on android tablets available around a building. No one can access settings or anything. It's fixed in a stand and displays stuff (just like a TV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used firebase messaging service and it worked like a charm. As some member(s) might have mentioned, the downside of using notification is that it can be switched off from settings and then you lose your communicate channel with the App. It's best to use web sockets to have a full communicative channel with the App (but again, 4g/wifi can be switched off as well..).

I have followed the following tutorial to get started.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup [Click Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)